# Bash: CTRL+A prints ^A to stdout

Tags: bash, ubuntu, keyboard-shortcuts, gnome-terminal

A few days ago, my ubuntu console started printing '^A' whenever I hit 'CTRL+A', instead of moving the cursor to the start of the line as it did before. The same problem happens for 'CTRL+E', while the 'CTRL+Arrow' shortcuts behave as they should.
However, if I log in to a remote machine via ssh, everything works fine.
Unfortunately, I do not remember anything in particular which could have triggered this behaviour (I have not changed shortcuts, nor modified my '.bashrc' file, nor updated the system).

some useful information:

I am not using nor screen nor tmux or other terminal multiplexers;

```
joe@Zen:~$ lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 19.10
Release:    19.10
Codename:   eoan

joe@Zen:~$ echo $TERM
xterm-256color

joe@Zen:~$ ps -f -p$PPID
UID        PID  PPID  C STIME TTY          TIME CMD
joe      11539  1575  0 12:27 ?        00:00:04 /usr/libexec/gnome-terminal-server

joe@Zen:~$ echo $SHELL
/bin/bash

joe@Zen:~$ cat /proc/version
Linux version 5.3.0-62-generic (buildd@lcy01-amd64-018) (gcc version 9.2.1 20191008 (Ubuntu 9.2.1-9ubuntu2)) #56-Ubuntu SMP Tue Jun 23 11:20:52 UTC 2020
```

Thank you in advance if you give me some ideas about what could I try.

Comment: Try `set -o emacs`

Comment: @roaima Thank you very much, this actually solved the problem. I don't know when or why, but I probably messed up with vim.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest that you have inadvertently changed your line editing scheme from the default "emacs" to "vi".

You can reset this back with

```
set -o emacs
```

Or change it back to `vi` mode with

```
set -o vi
```